# Embed pods framework - Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

When I am trying to run my project on a device or to archive it, I am getting this error:

[image: error screen]

I have allready tried to delete derived data, deintegrate and clean pods but nothing helped. Appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the code signing is failing. Are you sure you gave access to keychain when Xcode prompted you for it? If not, then try going to KeychainAccess and unlocking the keychain that has your signing assets (usually the login keychain).

**Edit:**
Go to Keychain Access and in the login keychain find your iOS Developer key under 'Keys'. Double click on the key and change the access control either to allow all apps to access or uncheck 'Ask for keychain password' under 'Confirm before allowing access'. Then restart Xcode and try building again.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am sure I denied access because it did not accept the password. I iterated over all keychains and they seems to be unlocked. What name that keychain could have...?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Most likely you named your app with a space in the name and cocoapods can't do proper string escaping.

Go to a file `Pods-YourAppName-frameworks.sh`, do a search for "entitlements", you will see something like this:

[image]

Change double quotes surrounding `$1` to single quotes like this: `entitlements '$1'"`. Run your workspace again, it should work now.